# How to send a struct of strings using ZMQ

Tags: c++, string, struct, zeromq

I would like to compare the latency between two nodes, A and B, of a cluster by comparing the timestamp of both at the receiving node B. For this, i am utilizing a preexisting struct of integers, but with adding a string to hold the timestamp of node A.

The struct looks like that:

```
struct Content {
  int id;
  double a;
  std::vector<char> timestamp;
};
```

To prepare the data at node A, i am using the following:

```
int fEventSize = 100;

Content* payload = new Content[fEventSize];

boost::posix_time::ptime mst1 = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time();

std::string str = to_simple_string(mst1);
std::vector<char> writable(str.begin(), str.end());
writable.push_back('\0');

(&payload[0])->timestamp = writable;
```

I subsequently create a ZMQ message, i memcpy payload to the message and i send it to node B as usual. To verify that the timestamp was written correctly at node A, the following works ok:

```
cout << &(&payload[0])->timestamp[0]; << endl;
```

But at the receiving end of node B, although i can properly print the value of the id and a members of the struct, i get a segmentation fault when i try to print the value of the timestamp:

```
Content* input = reinterpret_cast<Content*>(msg->GetData());

cout << "x: " << (&input[0])->x << endl;

cout << "timestamp: " << &(&input[0])->timestamp[0] << endl;
```

Why is that? Is this the correct way to send struct string members using ZMQ?

Comment: Why are you doing `(&input[0])->x` instead of `input[0].x` or `input->x`

Comment: This was already part of the code. Is it wrong though?

Comment: Not wrong just superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my question, the following works for me:

The struct looks like that:

```
struct Content {
  int id;
  double a;
  char timestamp[30];
};
```

On node A:

```
//Create a high resolution timestamp in microseconds
boost::posix_time::ptime mst1 = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time();

//Convert the timestamp into an std::string
std::string str (to_simple_string (mst1));

//Copy the string to the struct member
std::size_t length = str.copy ((&payload[0])->timestamp, strlen(str.c_str()), 0);
(&payload[0])->timestamp[length]='\0';

//Copy the contents of the Content struct to the ZMQ message
memcpy(msg->GetData(), payload, fEventSize * sizeof(Content));
```

On node B:

```
//Cast the data to an input pointer of type Content
Content* input = reinterpret_cast<Content*>(msg->GetData());

std::cout << (&input[0])->timestamp << std::endl;
```

BUT, actually there is a better solution, that is to send directly the timestamp across the wire:

The struct looks like that:

```
struct Content {
  int id;
  double a;
  boost::posix_time::ptime timestamp;
};
```

On node A:

```
(&payload[0])->timestamp = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time();

//Copy the contents of the Content struct to the ZMQ message
memcpy(msg->GetData(), payload, fEventSize * sizeof(Content));
```

On node B:

```
//Cast the data to an input pointer of type Content
Content* input = reinterpret_cast<Content*>(msg->GetData());

//Convert the timestamp into a string
std::string mystr (to_simple_string ((&input[0])->mytimestamp));
cout << mystr.c_str() << endl;
```

This way, a lot of fancy things can be done client-side without constantly converting between timestamps and strings like, for example, to calculate the send latency between nodes A and B (assuming that the nodes have a synchronized clock).